# Using Eclipse externalized Strings - how to get a String in language XYZ?

Tags: java, eclipse, string, locale

In our Eclipse RCP application, all Strings are externalized and present in 2 languages, which works just fine.
E.g. I got a Messages.java like this:

```
public class Messages extends NLS
{
  private static final String BUNDLE_NAME =
          "abc.fixedcolumns.messages"; //$NON-NLS-1$
  public static String additionalReq;

  static
  {
    // initialize resource bundle
    NLS.initializeMessages( BUNDLE_NAME, Messages.class );
  }




  private Messages()
  {
    super();
  }
```

With the matching messages_de.properties and messages_en.properties.

It works fine, starting the application in english shows the english strings and in german shows the german ones.

Now I need to get some English strings in the german version.
How can this be accomplished?

(One attempt was to change the Locale of the JVM, get the string and change it back, but this would be a very bad solution)

Comment: Can't you add the English strings to the `message_de.properties` with the same keys as in the `message_en.properties` file?

Comment: Well they have the same keys. So there is key1 = englishTrans in the english properties and key1 = germanTrans in the german. Adding english translation in the german properties is no solution

Comment: Then why are you trying to display Engligh in the German version?

Comment: I need some strings in english for tool tips (or more specific: it is specified ;) )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to put all your messages in the language specific properties file. `NLS` will also look in a `messages.properties` file. You could put the English only messages there and not put anything in the language specific properties.

Other than that `NLS` does not support doing a lookup for anything other than the current locale. You could make your own version of the class to do what you want, `NLS` is not very big.

Eclipse `e4` RCPs do support more flexible translation systems.

Comment: Hi! "Eclipse e4 RCPs do support more flexible translation systems", could you expand a bit on this?

Comment: @LppEdd I was probably thinking of the `@Translation` and `@Message` annotations - see [this blog](http://blog.vogella.com/2013/05/03/eclipse-internationalization-part-14-current-situation-by-dirk-fauth/) Also `IMessageFactoryService` and `ResourceBundleProvider`